# Query validation based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find out if a client who had a pharmacy visit (DateOfService) during the year 2017 was in a program type of 1 or 2 ONLY and that the DateOfService fell into the Start/End of the program(s) they were enrolled in.  Here is some example data.

```
Client Table (c)
ClientID    LastName    FirstName   SSN
12345       Smith       John        000-00-0000
54321       Johnson     Judy        111-11-1111

Client Program Table (cp)
ProgramID   ClientID    ProgramCode     StartDate   EndDate
001         12345       1               4/1/2016    4/1/2017
002         54321       1               4/1/2016    4/1/2017
003         54321       2               11/8/2017   11/8/2018

Program Code Table (cp1)
ProgramCode     Description
1               Medicaid
2               Medicare
3               PPO
4               HMO

Pharmacy Table (rx)
LastName    FirstName   DateOfService   SSN 
Smith       John        4/18/2016       000000000
Smith       John        1/1/2017        000000000   
Smith       John        2/1/2017        000000000
Johnson     Judy        11/1/2017       111111111
Johnson     Judy        12/15/2017      111111111
```

I'm pulling from the Pharmacy table ONLY with the DateOfService between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' (in this example that would be 4 records).  Client programs last for one year having a start/end date accordingly. I need to match up the person in the pharmacy table to the client table to pull/relate their info, so I matched them up on SSN.  I then joined the other tables to query for program data.  I'm just wondering if I'm doing this correctly to get everyone (based on my last line in my query) where I compare the DateOfService is between the program start/end date?  Any suggestions or feedback would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
  rx.LastName
 ,rx.FirstName
 ,rx.SSN
 ,rx.DateOfService
 ,cp1.Description
 ,cp.startDate
 ,cp.endDate
FROM pharmacy rx
INNER JOIN client c ON REPLACE(c.SSN,'-','') = rx.SSN
INNER JOIN client_program cp ON cp.ClientID = c.ClientID
INNER JOIN program_code cp1 ON cp1.ProgramCode = cp.ProgramCode
WHERE convert(char(10),rx.DateOfService,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
AND cp.ProgramCode in ('1', '2') --Medicaid --Medicare
AND convert(char(10),rx.DateOfService,120) BETWEEN cp.StartDate AND cp.EndDate
```

Before I had tried the following and it brings back more records, so I'm getting confused as to the correct way.  Thank you.

```
AND (convert(char(10),cp.EndDate,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
  OR convert(char(10),cp.StartDate,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31')
```

Comment: You mentioned `AND (convert(char(10),cp.EndDate,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
  OR convert(char(10),cp.StartDate,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31')` . What is the complete second query looks like?

Comment: The query was the same - only the last AND statement was replaced by the other one (using AND/OR) I listed. This gave back more records and wasn't sure if my logic was correct in using the program start/end dates this way.

Comment: What is the column data type for `DateOfService `, `StartDate `, `EndDate `?

Comment: I think first query is correct but second query is incorrect. I have updated my answer below to explain further. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think your first query is correct. Based on the way you described, your `where clause` fulfilled those condition you mentioned:

First query - **Correct**

```
-- a client who had a pharmacy visit (DateOfService) during the year 2017
WHERE convert(char(10),rx.DateOfService,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'

-- in a program type of 1 or 2 ONLY
AND cp.ProgramCode in ('1', '2') --Medicaid --Medicare

-- DateOfService fell into the Start/End of the program(s) they were enrolled in
AND convert(char(10),rx.DateOfService,120) BETWEEN cp.StartDate AND cp.EndDate
```

Second query - **Incorrect**

```
-- a client who had a pharmacy visit (DateOfService) during the year 2017
WHERE convert(char(10),rx.DateOfService,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'

-- in a program type of 1 or 2 ONLY
AND cp.ProgramCode in ('1', '2') --Medicaid --Medicare

-- program's StartDate or EndDate falls between 2017-01-01 and 2017-12-31
AND (convert(char(10),cp.EndDate,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
  OR convert(char(10),cp.StartDate,120) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31')
```

Second query only checks either program's StartDate or EndDate falls between 2017-01-01 and 2017-12-31, but it didn't ensure client pharmacy visit's date is within the program's StartDate & EndDate.

Consider these scenarios:

1) Client had a pharmacy visit during year of 2017, but her visit date is **before** her program start date:

```
rx.DateOfService = 2017-03-01
cp.StartDate = 2017-06-01
cp.EndDate = 2018-06-01
```

2) Client had a pharmacy visit during year of 2017, but her visit date is **after** her program start date:

```
rx.DateOfService = 2017-08-01
cp.StartDate = 2016-06-01
cp.EndDate = 2017-06-01
```

Second query will return these record which are unwanted, but first query will filter them out.

Comment: @DataCrypt I have edited my answer to explain more on the difference between your 2 queries. Can you take a look & see whether it helps?